# Encrypt some folder and hide key in Linux

Tags: security, encryption, pgp

I work on a Debian system (Mint actually).
I'd like to encrypt some folders and files, for instance: the one with OpenVPN configuration and keys, and be able to decrypt it on the fly.

My problem: where/how to hide the encryption key (in case of the machine is stolen and the key is found)?

Comment: I guess you should be more specific regarding what your understanding of "hiding" it. What exactly do you want to prevent? What is your definition of "hidden"?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by Mint? Are you running Linux Mint (Ubuntu based) or are you running LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition)?